# How to restore Linux with ACLs

Tags: linux, backup, acl

I created `dd` backup of whole system and I would like to restore it to new (encrypted) drive. I successfully used `rsync -ad` to restore files and permissions to newly created ext4 filesystem (I successfully booted it and I'm using it to write this), but I can't access devices mounted at `/media/username` (let's say I click some partition at file manager to mount it), this directory and mount points are owned by `root:root`. Permissions of known files (for example things in `/home`) are set correctly, so I assume `/media/*` was owned by `root` also before backup. I guess there is problem with *ACL*s.

- Is there a way to restore *ACL*s without having to copy everything second time? (I have found [this](https://www.linux.com/training-tutorials/how-easily-back-and-restore-linux-file-permissions/) guide, but it says it's not reliable. I don't know if this is good for my use case. Also I don't need to restore Linux ownership and permissions, that should already be correct and I don't want to break it. Maybe `-s` option of `getfacl` is what I need?)
- Is there anything else `rsync` omits and it needs to be restored?
- If saving this is not possible and I have to again copy everything, what should I use. Guide I followed used `tar` command, but It was really slow to pipe two `tar` commands.

I use *Linux Mint 19.3*.

edit:
I checked backup (`/mnt/`), I'm right, ACLs are set:

```
sudo getfacl /mnt/media/username/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: mnt/media/username/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:username:r-x
user:libvirt-qemu:--x
group::---
mask::r-x
other::---
```

edit2: I did some changes since I copied everything, so I would prefer method that will not overwrite content of files.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `rsync -avX` instead of of `rsync -ad`. It should apply any missing ACLs without recopying file content.

Add the `-u` flag to avoid updating changed files, and `--existing` to avoid creating new files (for example where you have deleted them in the target).

Answer (score 3):

Solution that worked for me (if you want to only restore ACLs and permissions but don't want to change files):

```
cd /path/to/backup  # so that saved paths would be relative to backed up root
getfacl -R . > ~/facl.bak
cd /
setfacl --restore=/root/facl.bak
```